# Selecting a <a> inside div

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I want to select the ID of the URL of the active class.

The situation is like this:

```
<ul id="links">
 <li id="active"> <a href="#" id="3"> </li>
 <li id="">       <a href="#" id="2"> </li>
 <li id="">       <a href="#" id="3"> </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
if (jQuery("#links li").is('#active')) {
          *do this*
}
```

The jQuery needs to get the ID of the A which LI got the ID 'active', but I can't figure out how to do this.
Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: try jQuery("#links li#active a").attr("id");

Comment: dont forget to close your links `</a>`

Comment: What do you want to get the ID? It's often a sign of a bad concept if you need to do that. (Also: an ID isn't allowed to start with a digit.)

Comment: _"Selecting a <a> inside div"_ - What div is that? @RoToRa - IDs can start with (or be nothing but) digits in html5, though you're right that the OP is probably on the wrong track in trying to use IDs rather than classes.

Comment: @nnnnnn Damn, these meddling kids, you are right. However an empty id attribute is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var id = jQuery("#links li#active a").attr("id");
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/xtzj7/

Comment: +1 for simplicity :-D, and to help you break the 9k barrier :-P

Answer (score 1):

The posted answers are correct, although I am not too sure about the '.id' property that some people have mentioned...

One thing to note is that the `id` attribute of an HTML element should be unique throughout the enitre DOM. Therefore, if you are going to assign more than one `li` to `active` then convert this to a class attribute. Your code will then look like this:

```
<ul id="links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="1"></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="2"></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

And then, to retrieve the id of the `a` tag within the `active` `li`, use the following:

```
var id = $('li.active a').attr('id');
```

For further information, please see the documentation for the `attr` attribute [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Furthermore, the `attr()` method can be use to extract any attribute information from an HTML element. For instance, if you wanted to get the `href` instead of the `id`, then use the following:

```
var href = $('li.active a').attr('href');
```